# how call my function after remove attachment button clicked in phpfileuploader?

Tags: php, jquery

i used http://phpfileuploader.com script .

**i need call my function after remove button attachment clicked**.

[image]

Comment: y not a click handler for the remove button??
http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: i can not find handle of this script,i read document but i can not find any event or method to can get handler of remove button . u can see documents in links and see samples .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use it's Javascript API: http://phpfileuploader.com/document/index.htm#page=JavaScript-API.htm

Comment: i said later,i can not find event of remove attachment handler in that documents or any about remove button clicked.please help me

Comment: @barnameha use jQuery with click() to do this. All you need to know is how to detect those elements.

Comment: i make a contact with master of script site but not answered yet.i am waiting for slove this problem.

Comment: i said i read documents full but i can not find handler of remove button.i think script not defined this handler yet :-??

Comment: sloved this problem in this porst -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124323 - thanks