# how add event or add id attribute to img tag in last td in tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to set **attribute ID** to following highlighted img tag **or** find highlighted img tag and add onclick event.
How can I do that with jQuery?

---

```
<img src="/site/control/uploader/phpuploader/resources/stop.png" ...



<tbody>
<tr class="AjaxUploaderQueueTableRow" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<td style="white-space: nowrap;">
<img src="/site/control/uploader/phpuploader/resources/circle.png" title="" width="16" height="16">
</td>
<td style="width: 456px;">Tales&nbsp;from&nbsp;the&nbsp;Dark&nbsp;1&nbsp;(2013).jpg</td>
<td style="white-space: nowrap;">
<img src="/site/control/uploader/phpuploader/resources/stop.png" title="Remove" width="16" height="16" style="cursor: pointer;">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: When do you want to set the id attribute?

Comment: `$('td img:last').prop('id', 'whatever')`

Comment: this table dynamic created with phpfileuploader script when a file selected by open dialog but this scrip not defined any remove button click event i want find and add click event on last img tag in tbody or defined id attribute to can used in jquery click event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dunno when you want to do this, but this will set the id using jquery:

```
$('tr.AjaxUploaderQueueTableRow img:last').attr('id', 'yourID');
```

To find last td and then find img tag, becuase img maybe not last:

```
$('tr.AjaxUploaderQueueTableRow td:last img').attr('id', 'yourID');
```

If you want to click on that and add a 'highlight' class, that would be:

```
var lastTlbImg = $('tr.AjaxUploaderQueueTableRow td:last img');

lastTlbImg.click(function(){
    lastTlbImg.addClass('highlight');
})
```

Comment: are u sure ?!!! my writed codes is a part of codes in all html codes  maybe i used 10 tables in a page this code find which table ?!!! or tr ?

Comment: what does "my writed codes is a part of codes in all html codes" mean, i dont get what you are saying. This selector will find all the img tags inside of the last td in a tr tag.

Comment: how can find last img in AjaxUploaderQueueTableRow tr class ?

Comment: my means writed codes in my questions is not all of codes in page and i used for example 10 tbody i want find AjaxUploaderQueueTableRow class in this tbody and then find last img tag in last td and ...

Comment: what do you mean by this tbody?

Comment: for example just like this <tbody> ... <tbody><tbody> ... <tbody><tbody> ... <tbody><tbody> ... <tbody> i writed this code here-> <tbody><tr> <td></td>  <td></td> <td> <img ...> </td> </tr><tbody><tbody> ... <tbody><tbody> ... <tbody>

Comment: first, you have no closing tags, which makes what you said hard to interpret, but i think the answer i have is fine

Comment: thanks watson your updated code worked but i have another question about your code ,how can change your code to i can find last td and then find 2nd ot 3th img tag becuase img maybe not was last ?

Comment: i added $("#yourID").click(function(){alert('clicked');}) but not worked now  if i want add for example click event to this $('tr.AjaxUploaderQueueTableRow td:last img').attr('id', 'yourID'); ?

Comment: what would you be clicking on?

Comment: for example onclick call myfunction

Comment: i ask again, what would you be clicking on?

Comment: my means just like this : $('tr.AjaxUploaderQueueTableRow td:last img').attr('id', 'yourID').click() or $('tr.AjaxUploaderQueueTableRow td:last img').click()

Comment: but not worked up code

Comment: i can find bind command but any body here can say another way ?!

Answer (score 0):

> updated

http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/2FCv6/2/

```
$("table:first tr td:last-child img").attr('id','blue').on('click', function(){
alert('clicked');

});
```

Comment: updated my answer. I forgot to select the img in the last td.

Comment: kasper thanks but why used first this table not is first or last .  can you doing change ur codes to can find unknow table but find  tr by class name and find last tr and last td and find img tag and ... ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand :-(